# How do I get the inner html text for a label element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the inner html of this element.

```
<label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_chkUsers_0">DOE, RICHARD A(033495)</label>
```

However my jquery returns undefined for `customerLabel`.

```
var customerLabelId = $('label:contains("ContentPlaceHolder_chkUsers_0")').attr("for");
var customerLabel = $('#' + customerLabelId);
var customerValueInInnerHtml = customerLabel.val();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.filter()` to get the element that have `ContentPlaceHolder_chkUsers_0` in for attribute.

Also, `.val()` is for getting value of form elements like input, select ,textarea. You would need to use `.html()` or `.text()` to get label contents:

```
 $('label').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('for').indexOf("ContentPlaceHolder_chkUsers_0") > -1;
 }).html();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fr1o558p/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use "text()" if you want to get only text.

```
var customerValueInInnerHtml = customerLabel.text();
```

Use ".html()" if you want inner html with all html tags:

```
var customerValueInInnerHtml = customerLabel.html();
```

Use ".val()" if you want to get value of element like input, textarea, select